# How to change the resolution of the screen (number of pixels) on a project in assembly language (DOSBox)

Tags: assembly, x86, screen-resolution, dosbox, vesa

Actually I am making a project in assembly language where I am printing mountains, sea, and soil on assembly language display memory. I just want to make my movements smooth or my resolution higher so that my pixels would be more clear. I want my 80x25 screen changed into a bigger one to increase resolution. Somewhat near 800 or 1280.

I have tried using `int 10h` services. I have used functions 01h, 06h and all related stuff but nothing changed at all.

Comment: Then forget about DosBox version <=0.86.9.  It doesn't emulate [INT10h/AH=0](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm) with AL>13h.

Comment: DOSBox (current version 0.74) has VESA functionality, so you should be looking at that in the documentation that comes with DOSBox (and google for the VESA api).

Answer (score 1):

DOSBox (current version 0.74) has VESA functionality, provided the options file has the required settings. Some of the settings in my options file are:

> [sdl]
> fullscreen=false
> fulldouble=false
> fullresolution=desktop
> windowresolution=1280x960
> output=openglnb

> [dosbox]
> machine=svga_s3

> [render]
> aspect=true
> scaler=normal2x

I wrote this little demo to prove that it works:

[image: Diagonals on 800x600]

```
  org  256

  mov  bx, 4115h        ; 32-bit 800x600 graphics
  mov  ax, 4F02h        ; VESA.SetVideoMode
  int  10h              ; -> AX
  cmp  ax, 004Fh
  jne  Abort
  call DrawDiagonals
  mov  ah, 00h          ; BIOS.GetKeystroke
  int  16h              ; -> AX
  mov  ax, 0003h        ; BIOS.SetVideoMode 80x25 text
  int  10h
Abort:
  mov  ax, 4C00h        ; DOS.Terminate
  int  21h
; ----------------------
DrawDiagonals:
  mov  cx, 600
  xor  eax, eax
  mov  ebx, 3200-4
.a:
  mov  dword [0C0000000h+eax], 004080C0h    ; 0RGB
  mov  dword [0C0000000h+ebx], 00C08040h    ; 0RGB
  add  eax, 3200+4
  add  ebx, 3200-4
  loop .a
  ret
; ----------------------
```

In a full-fledged application you would first ask VESA for its list with supported video modes, and then pick one for which you retrieve the characteristics (like LinearFrameBuffer address, BytesPerScanline, ...).
Consult [the VESA documentation](https://www.phatcode.net/downloads.php?id=221&action=get&file=vbe30.pdf).